# Python: How to use boolean to subset dataframe dynamically (by on-off switching)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, subset

When subseting a dataframe, I know that we can use pass through slicing criteria like:

```
df[ (df.A > 3) & (df.B < 6) ]
```

But if I wonder how can we program a control mechanism to the criteria? Let me be specific, what I wanna achieve is something like...

```
A_larger_than_3 = True 

B_smaller_than_6 = False

df[ ((df.A > 3) * A_larger_than_3) & ((df.B < 6) * B_smaller_than_6)]
```

In this example, the first boolean is True while the second is False, which equivalent to execute

```
df[ (df.A > 3)]
```

I tried this exact code above, it works fine when all the booleans are True. But when one of them is False, it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's see why your example would fail when one of `A_larger_than_3` and `B_smaller_than_6` is False.

Given

```
df[ ((df.A > 3) * A_larger_than_3) & ((df.B < 6) * B_smaller_than_6)]
```

Say, `B_smaller_than_6` is False.

`((df.B < 6) * B_smaller_than_6)` will be all False or all zeros more precisely.

Next you are taking `&` between `((df.A > 3) * A_larger_than_3)` and `((df.B < 6) * B_smaller_than_6)`. Because `((df.B < 6) * B_smaller_than_6)` is all False. The evaluation of the `&` operation will also be all False. Thus, you will get nothing.

Before moving on, you might want to review some truth table. You can check out https://medium.com/i-math/intro-to-truth-tables-boolean-algebra-73b331dd9b94

For the goal you want to achieve. In my understanding, say there are two conditions, `C1` and `C2`, you want to be able to evaluate `C1 & C2`, `C1`, `C2`. I think you can use the following.

```
df[(C1 + (~C1) * B1) & (C2 + (~C2) * B2)]
```

`~C1` inverts `C1`. You now control `B1` and `B2` as your switch.

- If you want `df[C1]`, set `B2 = True` and `B1 = False`. Now the right-hand side of `&` will be all True. What's left on the left-hand side of `&` is `C1` since `B1` is `False` now. `C1 & MAT_ALL_TRUE` will be `C1`. (If you want `C2` set `B2 = False` and `B1 = True`.)
- If you want `df[C1 & C2]`, then set `B1 = False` and `B2 = False.